# How to fix CS0176 In this condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to access a static variable.  I fix some but some still error.  Here is the code which has a static value:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    static public bool hovered;
    static public int SlotNum;
    static public GameObject item;
    static public int ID;
    static public string Type;
    static public string Desc;
    static public bool empty;
    static public Transform SlotIconGO;
    static public Sprite Icon;
    static public Sprite Transparent;
    public GameObject Player;




    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = true;
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = false;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        UseItem();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        hovered = false;
        SlotNum = int.Parse(this.name);
        print("SlotNum for slot " + this.name + " = " + SlotNum);
        SlotIconGO = transform.GetChild(0);
        Icon = Transparent;
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        UpdateSlot();
    }
    public void UpdateSlot()
    {
        SlotIconGO.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Icon;
    }

    public void UseItem()
    {

        GuyAnimation GrnAni = Player.GetComponent<GuyAnimation>();
        GrnAni.GiveWeaponID(ID);
        item.GetComponent<Item>().ItemUsage(SlotNum);
    }

}
```

This is the code which tries to access the static variable, but can't:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool InventoryEnabled;
    public GameObject inventory;
    public GameObject Slotsholder;
    public GameObject WM;
    static public float Health = 1;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int AllSlots;

    public GameObject[] Slotv { get; private set; }

    private int EnabledSlots;



    public void Start()
    {
        AllSlots = 55;
        Slotv = new GameObject[AllSlots];

        for(int a = 0; a < AllSlots; a++)
        {
            Slotv[a] = Slotsholder.transform.GetChild(a).gameObject;

            if (Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().item == null)
            {
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().empty = true;
            }
        }

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            InventoryEnabled = !InventoryEnabled;
        }

        if(InventoryEnabled == true)
        {
            inventory.SetActive(true);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            inventory.SetActive(false);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Item")
        {
            GameObject IPU = other.gameObject;
            Item item = IPU.GetComponent<Item>();

            AddItem(item.Type, item.Desc, item.ID, item.Icon, IPU);
        }
    }

    void AddItem(string type, string desc, int id, Sprite icon, GameObject Object)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < AllSlots; a++)
        {
            if (Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().empty)
            {
                Object.GetComponent<Item>().PickedUp = true;

                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().item = Object;
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().Icon = icon;
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().Type = type;
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().ID = id;
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().Desc = desc;

                Object.transform.parent = Slotv[a].transform;
                Object.SetActive(false);

                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().UpdateSlot();
                Slotv[a].GetComponent<Slot>().empty = false;

                return;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here Is The Full Error

```
error CS0176: Member 'Slot.Icon' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error CS0176: Member 'Slot.item' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error CS0176: Member 'Slot.Type' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error CS0176: Member 'Slot.Desc' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error CS0176: Member 'Slot.ID' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

error CS0176: Member 'Slot.Icon' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you make something static, it will be shared among all instances. You don't want to use static in this case. The second block doesn't use the `Slot` class at all. You might need to define the `public GameObject[] Slotv` as `public Slot[] Slotv`. I don't know much about unity enough for that.

Comment: Totally what Jeroen van Langen already said .. you definitely do not want these to be `static` ... rather seem like values to me that should belong to individual instances of `Slot`! Further be careful with parameter and variable naming .. `Object` is also a Unity type and people might get confused looking at your code. And: Don't use `GetComponent` repeatedly .. rather store the reference **once** and reuse it. `public Slot[] Slotv` is actually a very good idea since this way you don't need to use `GetComponent` at all

Comment: @JeroenvanLagen @derHugo Thanks For Help Me Deleting Those `GetComponent` But Some Still Not working And Give Me Some Error(CS0176).

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. Also, this is not an appropriate use for the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Comment: @ParnKittiwarakul In English, capitalizing every word can harm readability.